# Understanding tensorflow keras LSTM when activation='softmax'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

My understanding of the `activation` kwarg in `tf.keras.layers.LSTM` is the same as for any other layer (eg. `Dense`). But the following toy example will break.

```py
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from numpy.random import uniform

m = Sequential([
    LSTM(5, activation='softmax')
])

m.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
)

x = uniform(size=(10, 5, 3))
y_pred = m.predict(x)
assert all(y_pred.sum(axis=1) == 1), 'Predictions are not a valid categorical distribution'
```

This will fail. `y_pred.sum(axis=1)` will be a vector of random floats between 0 and 1 that do not sum to 1. Eg:

```py
[0.5083836, 0.50286007, 0.504391, 0.5309103, 0.5131448, 0.53934443, 0.5301699, 0.49676484, 0.51985925, 0.5021868]
```

It seems that LSTM does not apply a valid softmax here. Is this by design and I'm just not understanding the fundamentals of `LSTMCell`?

Of course, I can achieve a proper softmax distribution by appending `tf.keras.layers.Softmax()` but I'm curious why this should be necessary.

Comment: To what value does y_pred sum to?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy - edited to make more clear what the current behavior is of the toy model, and an exmaple of what y_pred evaluates to. If you're asking about the sum across the batch dimension, I'm not sure what that tells us. It will depending on the random initialization of the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sum to one because the activation here is directly apply on each hidden unit, as @joelthchao said on [GitHub](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6255)

Comment: Perfect — not sure how I missed that Github issue! Thanks.